# Asp.NET application is supressing errors on localhost.. Why?

Tags: asp.net, visual-studio, debugging, error-handling, visual-studio-debugging

I am working on a web application, developing in VS 2012, and have lately been deploying fairly often to a test server.  I keep a separate web.config for deployment, as I got tired of copying and pasting connection strings...  Aside from the connection strings, the files are identical.

```
<compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
```

I'm set to "Debug" in Configuration Manager..  To be clear, if I run the application in "Debug" mode (f5) then VS will break and display an error like so:

[image]

What isn't happening any more, is if I run without debugging (ctl+f5) the browser won't display the error/strack trace..  I need my stack trace!

```
<customErrors mode="Off" />
```

as well..  What gives?

**EDIT:** Even though I mention uploading this to a test server, the issues I'm having only relate to my local copy.  When I run the hosted application on the test server (which points to a different db altogether) the application will show the errors and the stack trace when it breaks..

When I run my local development copy of the web app, with my local database, the application will either suppress the error if I run out of debug mode, or will break on the error in VS if I *am* in debug mode as depicted in the image above.

I'm looking to fix the issue that I'm having on my dev machine, so that I can quickly see an error and stack trace when not running in debug mode.

Comment: Are you accessing the test server locally (ie - http://localhost/yourapp/)? AFAIK, the default error pages won't show the stack track for a remote request.

Comment: No, I'm not..  I'm accessing a local DB.  My development and test databases are separate.

Comment: If you need to see the stack traces, you'll either need to load the site from the test server, or use something like [ELMAH](http://code.google.com/p/elmah/) or [Health Monitoring](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb398933%28v=vs.100%29.aspx) to get the details.

Comment: I don't understand what the test server has to do with anything though..  I'll update the question so that it's more clear